# Unity Geometryshader for one Vertex

Tags: shaders, graphics, unity, geometry-shader

Hy, 
I want to build some geometry with a geometryshader in Unity.
I took a look at [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/744622/constructing-a-cube-primitive-using-shader.html). I want to create my geometry just in context of one point in 3D space (x,y,z). Can i somehow use the transform position vector as input value for the shader? Or is there Something like a one vertex mesh I could use? I tried [this](https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-geo/wiki/One-vertex-mesh-object-at-the-cursor-location) in Blender, but coulnd't import that single Vertex mesh into Unity.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I haven't yet tested to confirm, but I think you can use the Mesh class to create a new mesh with one vertex, then `mesh.SetIndices(new int[]{0}, MeshTopology.Points)` to create exactly one point primitive pointing at the first vertex. Does that get you the one-point mesh you're looking for? If not, can you describe in more detail what you're trying to do with your shader?

Comment: Thanks, i will try it out. I want to archive a Lasereffetct https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Lasershow_Halifax_20070610.jpg. I did it before with linierenderers but it was very uneficcient, now i want to try it with a shader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked. My Code:

```
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
    mesh.vertices = newVertices;
    mesh.uv = newUV;
    GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
    mesh.SetIndices(new int[] { 0 }, MeshTopology.Points, 0);
```

The last line creates was very important to create a trinagle.
For saving the Mesh:

`AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(m1, "Assets/" + "oneVertexMesh" + ".asset"); // saves to "assets/"
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();`

Comment: You might not need the `mesh.triangles = newTriangles` line, since it's effectively overwritten by the later `SetIndices` call (the `triangles` setter is basically just a shortcut version of SetIndices for the common case where you're using triangular topology, rather than points)